# difference between ordinal and discreet numerical variable

Tags: statistics

From my current understanding an ordinal variable is a set of ordered options for example how much a person agrees with something, whereas a numerical variable is just a number such as temperature. However, I don't understand where things like a score on a test fall here as it seems that it fits both categories.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinal categorial variables have order, but not necessarily numerical values.
Opinion categories such as 'stongly opposed', 'somewhat opposed', 'neutral',
'somewhat favor', and 'favor' are ordinal. Sometimes people use numbers
such as $-2$ through $+2$ for such categories, perhaps for easy coding
in a worksheet, or (more controversially) in order to get numerical "averages."

Grades A, B, C, etc. are ordinal. But scores on an exam would ordinarily
be considered numerical variables, even if they are discrete (possibly taking
only integer values).

Sometimes numerical variables such as income are collected in
interval categories 'Low', 'Middle', and 'High' because people do not
want to reveal exact incomes.